# Convert YUV into HSL or HSV bypassing the RGB step

Tags: colors, yuv, hsv, color-space, hsl

Wikipedia and plethora of online resources provide detailed and abundant help with various color space conversions from/to RGB. What I need is a **straight YUV->HSL/HSV conversion**.

In fact what I need is just the **Hue** (don't care much for the Saturation or the brightness Lightness/Value). In other words I just need to calculate the "color angle" for a given YUV color.

Code in any language would suffice, though my preference is C-style syntax.

Note that by YUV I mean specifically Y′UV, a.k.a. YCbCr (if that makes any difference).

Comment: You should know that we cannot recommend any library or software to do this. We can help with code you  wrote but we can't write it for you either.

Comment: @Rob Would you recommend to move this into a different SE site? If so - which one? (I can write the code myself, no biggie. I need help with the algorithm for color space conversion)

Comment: Good question. There is a Graphics SE and a Math one. I'd be interested in this solution myself though I have a few algorithms stashed away that I've not looked at in decades.

Comment: I have thought of both (plus the "photo/video") but none seemed appropriate, TBH. Which is why this question ended up here - where I hoped I'd have a better chance at attracting people that are "interested in this solution" themselves, much like what you said above.

Comment: Look at the Gaming one. Some of the same people there. I don't know if the other SE sites have the same restrictions on recommendations.

Comment: So I checked all the suggested sites and (simply based on the available tags) none of them is as close a fit for this question as SO. I'll keep it here for now since I can't find a better fit for it :(

Comment: There are multiple non-linear conversions in the chain from Y'CbCr to HSV, none of them is a linear colourspace, so you will not find an affine transform mapping the twos.

Comment: @KelSolaar Thank you! That reasoning "non-linear transfomrs" is exactly the one I myself have arrived at a few hours ago. Was just hoping I was wrong...

Comment: You were correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While YUV->RGB colorspace conversion **is linear** (same as "can be expressed as a matrix operation") the RGB->HSL **is not**. Thus it is not possible to combine the two into a single operation.

Thank you Kel Solaar for confirming this for me.

For reference:

- [YUV(YCbCr)->RGB conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.601_conversion)
- [RGB->HSL conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#General_approach)

Note that mathematically the calculation for Hue is written piecewise as the "base angle" depends on which sector the color is in and the "major color" is driven by the `max(R, G, B)` expression.

Comment: I would like to add that even though the relationship between Y'CbCr and RGB is linear, the transformation is actually Y'CbCr to R'G'B'. The primes are here to denote the non-linearity of the components being transformed and. The Y' of Y'CbCr is for Luma, not Luminance. This imply that you might also want to decode your non-linearly encoded R'G'B' colours to linear RGB colours before converting to HSV.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are from the different worlds of interest. Here is a google patent
https://patents.google.com/patent/CN105847775A/en

Comment: Just read the patent and... how is it different from a lookup table? ;-) Which also makes its space requirements unpractical in any application with limited RAM